# ERROR:process_metrics.cc NOT IMPLEMENTED error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

Recently, we've started to get these kind of warnings on the console when running Protractor tests:

```
[12252:14584:1207/223118.187:ERROR:process_metrics.cc(105)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
[12252:14584:1207/223118.187:ERROR:process_metrics.cc(105)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
[12252:14584:1207/223318.188:ERROR:process_metrics.cc(105)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
```

It feels like they happen randomly but doesn't affect the test execution.

The only problem is that they pollute the output console making it more difficult to keep track of tests being executed and test results reported by jasmine/protractor.

Is there a way to turn off this kind of `chromedriver` warnings?

Using Protractor 5.2.2, ChromeDriver 2.34.

---

We've found this `--silent` flag that can be passed to `chromedriver` executable, but could not find a way to configure protractor to pass this flag when launching chromedriver..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with chrome v63

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5189#issuecomment-351605839

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pass the `--silent` flag to chromedriver in your conf file. Something like:

```
capabilities: {
    browserName' : 'chrome',
        'chromeOptions' : {
            args: ['--silent']
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think `chromeOptions` are the Chrome flags, not the ChromeDriver flags..but I'll give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, tried that but did not help - still getting the warning messages on the console. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

"This warning message was generated by a bug in Chrome v63.

Upgrading to v64 (64.0.3282.167 as of this morning) resolves it."