# protractor hanging on element click

Tags: javascript, angular, selenium, protractor

I've got an angular 5.x project.  I'm trying to execute some e2e tests with Protractor.  I've got a few simple tests running that simply check the browser title and check for the presence of basic elements.

I'm now trying to do more complex tests where I interact with the page.  Unfortunately clicking an element causes a nasty hang that never comes back (not even after 30-60 seconds).  Any ideas what could be causing this, or how I could even troubleshoot?

**Tests that work:**

```
it('should have correct title', () => {
  expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual("My App");
});

it('should have a login button', () => {
  let loginButton = element(by.id('btnLogin'));
  var untilLoginIsVisible = ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(loginButton);
  browser.wait(untilLoginIsVisible, 20000);
  expect(loginButton.isDisplayed()).toEqual(true);
});
```

**Test that hangs - note similarity with successful test above**

```
it('show login transition', () => {
  let loginButton = element(by.id('btnLogin'));
  var untilLoginIsVisible = ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(loginButton);
  browser.wait(untilLoginIsVisible, 20000);

  //EITHER ONE OF THESE FAILS, AND JUST HANGS FOREVER
  loginButton.click().then(() => { console.log("Clicked, yo!"); });
  browser.actions().mouseMove(loginButton).mouseDown(loginButton).mouseUp().perform();
});
```

**Other info:**

- I've tried other buttons on the page - same result
- While I get no errors, after ~60 seconds I do get an `F` in the output, indicating a failed test, but it never moves to the next test
- After ~2 minutes it starts spitting out `ERROR:process_metrics.cc(105)] NOT IMPLEMENTED` which I don't think is the source of the problem (similar unrelated complaints [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5189))

Comment: What happens if you would put a, say, `browser.sleep(30000)` after `browser.wait(untilLoginIsVisible, 20000);` and then click the login button manually in the opened browser - do you see the desired result? In other words, I am trying to see if there is any problem with the application or the application build itself..thanks.

Comment: FYI, `ERROR:process_metrics.cc(105)] NOT IMPLEMENTED` is a [Chrome 63 issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47783989/771848). Should not be related to what you have here.

Comment: What code gets run when you click an element? Put a breakpoint in the sources at the start of the code that gets run and then step through the code until you (hopefully) find the issue. You can do all of this in Chrome even if you don't own the site.

Comment: Have you tried `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable()` instead?

Comment: @alecxe - if I remove the protractor click and I do it manually, the app responds and the tests pass.  Adding the protractor click back in hangs forever.  @HaC - I adjusted to `elementToBeClickable()`, and same result.  The element is clickable so it flies right past that.  Then the click hangs forever.

Comment: @JeffC - This is a SPA, and clicking this element just moves to a different page within the app.  Manually clicking works fine, so it doesn't seem to be an app issue.  Something with my protractor setup isn't liking the click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the cause for this.  I'm using `multiCapabilities` to test various browsers & sizes.  Unfortunately my first capability was using mobile emulation:

```
   chromeOptions: {
     'mobileEmulation': {
       'deviceName': 'iPhone 4'
     },
```

This was the trigger to making clicks completely hang.  Below is some more info on what works and what doesn't.

**Works on non-mobile emulation, hangs on mobile emulation**

```
loginButton.click().then(() => { console.log("Clicked, yo!"); });
```

**Works with mobile emulation**

```
browser.touchActions().tap(loginButton).perform().then(() => { console.log("Tapped, yo!"); });
```

It's unfortunate that whatever is causing this made protractor hang completely and not give any errors.  Moving to the next capability would have made this more obvious.  A follow-up question I'll need to deal with is if all mobile emulation tests need to use `tap()` in place of `click()`...

Comment: I have come across a similar issue, an <a> that can be clicked in either full chrome or mobile emulation mode through chromedriver (both v83) using multiCapabilities setup but only a single capability listed, but when test suite is run with both capabilities simultaneously the mobile emulation shows element as not interactable.  Changing mobile to use tap does not fix.  I will report back if I find a solution.

Comment: Same problem occurs with multipleCapabilities using the same mobile emulation but not 2 instances of desktop chrome.